# How to use pretrained model by TF 2.x in C++

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have trained segmentation and classification network in python using **Tensorflow 2.1**. The Model is saved using SavedModel (.pb). Now, I want to test the model, I need this to be done in C++.
I saw many information about C++ API for **Tensorflow 1.x**, except TF 2.x.
The official tensorflow site says "Note: There is no libtensorflow support for TensorFlow 2 yet. It is expected in a future release.".

Does anyone know of a possible way?
It will be great help to me.

Thanks.

Comment: Never worked with C++ TF API, but there are some TF 2.x docs about loading SavedModel to C++. Maybe they will be of help:  
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#load_a_savedmodel_in_c

Comment: However, are you open to considering using the Tensorflow C API instead of C++ API?